# Applying Ajax-jQuery to Dynamically Created Rows - in Yii

Tags: jquery, dynamic, yii

If anyone can give me some idea, I’ve tried everything and have come up with nothing.

i got cJUIcomplete working bt what i am working on  - Inventory Management

on sale form - my idea to build in a way like

Product Name  - Open Stock  - Quantity - Price - Total  (Add New ROW)

in Product Name Text Box i used CJUIcomplete for searching the product name from n number of list.

when i selected any product the fields open stock and Price should show values accordingly selected product from product model.

please help me on this issue.

THanks
Devendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing any actual code it's hard to know where things are.

```
$('#myGridId').on('click', 'thead tr th:last-child a', function() {
//Do something here.
});
```